# Une expression qui équivaut à « defeat the purpose » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Bonjour tout le monde,

Je cherche, à présent en vain, une expression qui veut dire à peu près:

> to defeat the purpose [of something] <sup>*****</sup>

Je suis parvenu à la page suivante qui contient plein de suggestions, mais selon ce que je vois, pas de consensus: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/defeat-the-purpose.111970/.

Donc, je pose la question ici.

<sup>*****</sup> L'expression veut dire que nous voulons faire X, mais entretemps, disons, nous faisons Y, ce qui rend X inutile ou pas possible.

**Exemple 1:**

- Je veux perdre du poids
- Je vais à la salle du sport tous les jours
- Mais chaque samedi et dimanche, je mange tout ce que veux, et je bouge pas, donc, "defeating the purpose" de ce que je fais pendant la semaine

**Exemple 2**

- Un enfant pas très sage se retrouve puni, privé de sortie pendant le weekend
- Cependant, il peut jouer avec sa Switch, regarder la télé, etc., et donc, il n'est pas si malheureux
- Je trouve donc que le laisser faire tout ce qu'il veut à la maison "defeats the purpose of the initial punishment"

**Exemple 3**

- Je me lève tôt, voire très tôt, le matin afin d'avoir plus de temps pour accomplir tout ce que je dois pendant la journée
- Mais je commence à sentir la fatigue très tôt le soir, et je me couche donc très tôt
- Finalement, je me rends compte que je suis debout les mêmes seize heures qu'avant, ce qui "defeats the purpose of waking up so early to begin with".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ex. 1:

> Je vais à la salle de sport tout les jours mais le weekend, je glandouille en me gavant de cochonneries, torpillant mes efforts de la semaine.

Ex. 2:

> Je trouve donc que le laisser faire tout ce qu'il veut à la maison réduit à néant l'objectif de la sanction.

Ex. 3:

> Finalement, je me rends compte que, comme avant, je suis debout seize heures par jour, ce qui rend tout simplement vain un réveil si matinal.

D'autres verbes pouvant convenir :

Annihiler, anéantir, contrebalancer, aller à l'encontre.

Pour une formule plus générique, on pourrait suggérer, comme déjà fait par l'un des intervenants de wordreference :

> Ça va à l'encontre du but souhaité.

Comment: Merci, oui, je suis d'accord pour l'exemple dans la question mais je chercher quelque chose de plus général qui peut convenir aux plus de situations. Souvent, je me retrouve à vouloir dire "but that defeats the purpose" mais j'hésite à chaque fois, parce que je n'arrive pas à trouver la bonne expression en français. Je vais ajouter d'autres exemples dans la question.

Comment: Une formule générique serait: *ça va à l'encontre du but souhaité* (déjà suggéré dans wordreference).

Comment: Ah, ça oui effectivement je pense que ça marche. Pouvez-vous l'ajouter à votre réponse ? Je vais l'accepter.

Comment: PS: Mon "preferred pronoun" est **tu** :-)

Comment: C'est bien noté, je *te* souhaite une bonne journée

Answer (score 2):

On dit souvent* [**contre-productif**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/contre-productif/18863).

> *Mais chaque samedi et dimanche, je mange tout ce que veux, et je bouge pas, ce qui paraît **contre-productif**.*

Il me semble que ça s'utilise comme l'anglais [counterproductive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterproductive).

<sub>* : France métropolitaine, ouest ; le mot me paraît légèrement connoté 'monde de l'entreprise' à cause de 'productif'.</sub>

Comment: En effet ça marche aussi, mais en tant qu'anglophone, je trouve, peut-être à tort, que "defeats the purpose" est un peu plus fort que "counterproductive" et donc je cherchais quelque chose de plus ciblé, en quelque sorte. Mais je vais quand même garder « contre-productif » en tête, merci.